# Mysql data query returning an error

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT  d.sbjnum, d.name, d.scan_no, c.scanner  
FROM data AS d  
INNER JOIN check AS c ON d.sbjnum = c.sbjnum
```

---

> Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'check AS c ON d.sbjnum = c.sbjnum' at line 3

Do not know what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`check` is a reserved keyword in MySQL. Put it in ticks to escape it:

```
SELECT  d.sbjnum, d.name, d.scan_no, c.scanner  
FROM data AS d  
INNER JOIN `check` AS c ON d.sbjnum = c.sbjnum
```

Answer (score 0):

`AS` is used for creating an alias for a field, not for a table. For tables, just don't write that `AS` :)

```
SELECT  d.sbjnum, d.name, d.scan_no, c.scanner  
FROM data d  
INNER JOIN check c ON d.sbjnum = c.sbjnum
```

Answer (score 0):

`CHECK` is a mysql keyword. If u insist on using it, at least put it in backtiks.
And also remove the `AS` in the FROM part.

Answer (score 0):

`check` is a reserved keyword in MySQL.

You can change the alias name

```
SELECT  d.sbjnum, d.name, d.scan_no, c.scanner  
FROM data AS d  
INNER JOIN check1 AS c ON d.sbjnum = c.sbjnum
```

Or Put it in ticks to escape it:

```
SELECT  d.sbjnum, d.name, d.scan_no, c.scanner  
FROM data AS d  
INNER JOIN `check` AS c ON d.sbjnum = c.sbjnum
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try to add a semicolon (;) at the end of the request.

If still not working, please consider give us the CREATE TABLE command for these 2 tables.